# MySQL Trigger IF statement using Select

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on my table, so that when I insert data, it tries to take the data from one column (Notes) and update another table's (masterData) column notes (Additional) with the data. If it can't find it, I want the insert statement to be copied to a different table (failedtofind). My trigger is below, but it reports that there is a syntax error on my IF statement, and I can't quite get it working:

```
DELIMITER $$
TRIGGER `testdb`.`testTable`
AFTER INSERT ON `testdb`.`testTable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    IF ((SELECT PrimaryID FROM testdb.masterData WHERE PrimaryID = NEW.PrimaryID) > 0 )
        UPDATE masterData AS t
        SET t.Additional = NEW.Notes
        WHERE t.PrimaryID = NEW.PrimaryID;
    ELSE
        INSERT IGNORE INTO failedtofind SET (all the columns);
    END IF;

END$$
```

Also, is this the way I should be doing it? I'm a novice when it comes to databases, so, as always, if I'm doing something wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `THEN` after your `IF(...)` it should be

```
 IF ((SELECT PrimaryID FROM testdb.masterData WHERE PrimaryID = NEW.PrimaryID) > 0 ) THEN
 ...
```

I am not sure what the `> 0` is suppose to do - if no record with that PrimaryID is found the SELECT statement will evaluate to `NULL` (not 0). But it should still work as expected because `NULL > 0` evaluates to `NULL` and it will insert a row in `failedtofind`.

Comment: I'm using the '> 0' to determine if the PrimaryID exists in the masterData table, and if it does to update. If it doesn't (the NULL, o 0), Insert the failedtofind table.

Comment: Well it should work with the `> 0`. You should also be careful about getting more than one row in a `IF(SELECT ...)` (should be OK in this case if `PrimaryID` is a `PRIMARY KEY`).

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. PrimaryID is in fact the primary key, but thanks for the warning!